# .NET Regex performance

Tags: .net, regex, performance, regex-group

Currently, I am using the following regular expression to delete the first conversation item from an Outlook HTML mail item:

```
.*?>(([^:]+?):<.*?\2):
```

In order to remove the first conversation item, I just replace the first occurrence of group 1 by the value of group 2. That would look somewhat like this in .NET:

```
private static readonly Regex LAST_CONVERSATION_REPLACE_PATTERN = new Regex(@".*?>(([^:]+?):<.*?\2):", RegexOptions.Compiled);
// ...
MatchCollection matches = LAST_CONVERSATION_REPLACE_PATTERN.Matches(htmlMessageBody);
if (matches.Count > 0)
{
    Match match = matches[0];
    if (match.Groups.Count > 2)
    {
        return htmlMessageBody.ReplaceFirst(match.Groups[1].ToString(), match.Groups[2].ToString());
    }
}
```

`ReplaceFirst` is a string extension method of my own. However, the performance of this is a bit disappointing. While Regex Coach can apply this to huge mail items in a microsecond, it takes up to 10 seconds in the Outlook add-in.

The performance improves significantly if I replace the pattern by this explicit alternative:

```
.*?>(From:<.*?From):
```

Using that regex, it takes less than a second to get what I want. However, this would be language-specific and I would thus prefer the previous variant. Is there any way to speed things up in .NET? Or is there a third-party regex library which could perform better on this one?

Thanks for any suggestions and best regards

Pascal

Comment: Please find an example E-Mail here:
http://www.tempfiles.net/download/201207/253263/reception-comment-included.html

My intention is to remove the intermediate conversation item from Jane doe (including header information and body).

Comment: Obtw., since I'm only interested in the first match, I applied this workaround:

            `Match match = LAST_CONVERSATION_REPLACE_PATTERN.Match(htmlMessageBody);`
            `if (match.Success) { //...`

So it's only a matter of curiosity now anymore :-) .

Answer (score 1):

I can't really say what the reason for the slowness might be (I *could* if you posted some example text on which Outlook performs poorly).

But I do have some ideas to optimize the regex, although I would be surprised if they caused a significant improvement. But who knows - let's give it a try.

First, you don't need to make the plus lazy. Instead, you might want to make it possessive or use an atomic group. Also, a word boundary might help selecting a suitable starting point for your second match:

```
.*?>(((?>[^:]+)):<.*?\b\2):
```

Comment: .NET doesn't support possessive quantifiers, but you can use an atomic group instead.

Comment: @AlanMoore: Oops, I forgot about that. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately, the laziness does not seem to impact the performance at all. I removed all three of them - no effect. Neither had adding the word boundary, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's the `.*?` that's causing your problem, both of them.  For example, the first one forces the regex to stop and try to match at every single position from the beginning of the document.  Lucky for you, you don't need that part anyway.  But you really need to be more specific whenever you can, and not rely on `.*?` all the time.

Try this:

```
private static readonly Regex LAST_CONVERSATION_REPLACE_PATTERN 
    = new Regex(@"^(?>(\w+:).*)(?>\s+(?!^\1).*)+", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

I think it's safe to assume every header name will be at the beginning of its own line; this is email, after all.  It also makes the job a lot easier.  In fact, if you *can't* assume that, you may be screwed.

`^(?>(\w+:).*)` matches something that looks like a header name at the beginning a line, and the `.*` consumes the rest of that line.  Putting it in an atomic group ensures that, if the match attempt at the beginning of the line fails on a later part of the regex, it won't bother coming back to try other ways to match the line.

`(?>\s+(?!^\1).*)` consumes the line separator and the next line, but only after the lookahead verifies that it doesn't start with the target header name.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Unfortunately, I don't think we can assume the header to start on a new line, since it's an HTMLBody. I'll post an example of it in a bit.